# Electron load failed when set uiAccess true

Tags: electron, uac

I want to use electron to develop an app to show above lock screen. I need to set my window alwaysOnTop and set the uiAccess of the exe as true.
The exe can load index.html successfully without uiAccess change, but when I change the uiAccess to true, the exe can only create a window but the window is blank, sometimes it's white while sometimes it's black.
I tried to log some event and found that the crashed event was triggered if I open the exe with non-Administrator. If I open the exe with administrator, the 'did-finish-load' was triggered but the window is black, didn't show my index.html. How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you change the `uiAccess` value to `true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the cause is the parameter of setAlwaysOnTop. The type for windows should be "normal". After change to `mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'normal');`, it works well.